# Missing words after commas in these sentences?

Tags: grammar, american-english, commas

In the following sentence, why did the author use "thinking" after the comma? Is a word omitted after the comma?

> 1. I waited for two months, thinking that it would be bad time for him.

Should it be something like "I waited for two months and now I am thinking that it would be bad time for him"?

Again, in the sentence below (describing League of Legends), is something like a word omitted after comma? I just cannot figure out why they type like this. I mean it seems more like a present continuous tense without "subject + be."

> 2. Shaco's basic attacks poison his targets, slowing them for 2 seconds and causing minions and monsters to....

Comment: StackExchange disapproves of cross-posting to multiple SE sites; please avoid this in the future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing words after commas in these sentences?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63022/) on 
[English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a seemingly identical question from the same person is posted (and receiving due attention) on English Language Learners.

Answer (score 1):

**I waited for two months, thinking that it would be bad time for him**

This is perfectly correct English. The meaning is not however what you guessed. The real meaning is "I waited for two months, *because I was* thinking that it would be bad time for him". The second clause is an explanation of the first, not a continuation.

The second sentence is also correct. In this case the second clause is a clarification, explaining in what way the attacks poison the targets. "Attacks" here means Shaco's *modes of attack* - as opposed to any specific attack actions such as "Shaco's attack on the third Orc from the left." It is indeed present continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Those sentence clauses you have mentioned in your sentences are called **participial phrases**.

> If a participial phrase comes at the end of a sentence, a comma usually precedes the phrase if it modifies an earlier word in the sentence but not if the phrase directly follows the word it modifies.

```
The local residents often saw Ken wandering through the streets.
(The phrase modifies Ken, not residents.)
Tom nervously watched the woman, alarmed by her silence.
(The phrase modifies Tom, not woman.)
```

Source: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/627/02/

> When a participle phrase concludes a main clause and modifies a word
>   farther up in the sentence, you will need a comma. The pattern looks
>   like this:

```
Main Clause + , + Participle Phrase.
```

Check out this example:

```
Cooper enjoyed dinner at Audrey's house, agreeing to a large slice of cherry pie even though he was full to the point of bursting.
```

Source: http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/phrase.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is a common construction, with or without the comma. The core meaning is simply that the second clause happens at the same time as the first. In the particular case of "thinking" (or "hoping", "wishing" etc) it is explanatory, it shows the motivation for the first clause, but it can simply signify that simultaneity or as in you second example, an effect that is caused by the action in the first clause.

Comment: I think i have got it.for example,(i use my iphone to send off some music to her computer,buying from tony's electronic emporium.) The phrase modifies the iphone ,not computer,right?

Comment: Not quite, that sentence doesn't work, and if you modify it to "bought" it will refer to the computer. In your examples the second clause refers to the whole situation in the first clause, so a better example would be: "i use my iphone to send some music to her computer, hoping that she will like me more" = "I send music BECAUSE/AND I hope she will like me more".

Comment: Oh man!i got it.the second clause functions as adjective in the whole sentence,modifying the first sentence .right? I think i'm right:) and the example you mentioned above would also make sense if i change it into "i use my iphone to send some music to her,thinking that she will like it." Or it also can be "i use my iphone to send some music to her,hearing that she likes listening to the music."

Comment: Yes, that's it!